# InstantiationException in web service client calling Web Service deployed to JBoss

Tags: web-services, jboss, jax-ws, jaxb2

I'm deploying a StatelessSessionBean annotated with @WebService to JBoss. I'm taking the WSDL generated by JBoss to generate client stubs. My problem is in calling a method which returns a list of objects. If the list is empty the call succeeds however if the list is not empty then I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.soap.DeserializationException: Failed to read a response: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:         
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of com.companyname.api.ws.DataItemType                                                     
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.InstantiationException]]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at $Proxy34.getWorkflows(Unknown Source)
    at com.companyname.api.SimpleClient.go(SimpleClient.java:48)
```

Searching the web led me to this discussion here: http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=281780

However I have set the @XmlSeeAlso stuff correctly and it is present on the generated stub classes. I can confirm that the DataItemType class *is* abstract so it is not surprising that an attempt to instantiate it causes a problem. I'm not at all clear on why the DataItemType class is being instantiated at all (as it is abstract). This is the XML that is returned from the server (it looks about right to me):

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header></env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns2:getWorkflowsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.api.companyname.com/">
            <return>
                <id>
                    <identifier>1</identifier>
                    <version>0</version>
                </id>
                <goal>ENROLL</goal>
                <dataItemType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="DataItemTypeText">
                    <attributeName>email</attributeName>
                    <displayName>Email Address</displayName>
                </dataItemType>
                ...
            </return>
        </ns2:getWorkflowsResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of issues with the generated WSDL (note that it wasn't a handcrafted one). There was nothing specific that I changed which indicated why this particular exception was thrown (or why, for example, there wasn't a failure when generating the incorrect WSDL).

Once I adjusted the annotations so that a valid WSDL was created then I had further issues which the JAX-WS versions I was using. I ended up upgrading the version used by JBoss which, in turn, led to me needing put the newer JAX-WS jars in my JRE endorsed directory.

I'm not going to detail what I did in any more detail as there was no specific thing that I did that addressed this problem. If anyone else sees it I would suggest being very specific in the annotations you use to generate your WSDL and taking a careful look at your WSDL.

Comment: i am having same problem and dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Krishna can you give me any more details? I don't know if it is specifically related but trying different JAX-WS versions might be worthwhile. Also just being very careful with the annotations (and being aware that the different versions will handle them differently) might help.

Comment: Ya i am using JAX-WS only and ya I am making One Pojo class and Putting that Class as return type into another class. and when i am trying to make webservice of that class that is showing this error. its like when i am giving return type that class then its showing error like "Return type not supported that may cause error or result  in lose of data." that is something like that error what i am getting.

Comment: Sorry I don't really have any suggestions :( Did you make any progress? If you do sort it out maybe add a comment explaining what you did.

Comment: Okey let me post my Question it self so u will come to know what is Real prob is.. and ya u can give suggestion i dont really down vote people ever so feel free to give any suggestion.